# Choices JS Re-Initialize is not working for dynamic Row add

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I am using Choices JS Plugin in HTML Table, But when I increasing the Table row dynamically by jQuery the next Select is not working.

Initializing first time at Document ready function using -

```
new Choices('.pdt-name'); --> pdt-name is select field class
```

when I adding new row to this Table using this -

```
    function addRow(table) {
        var x = document.getElementById(table);
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        $('#TableName tbody:last-child').append(new_row);
        new Choices('.pdt-name'); -- Re assigning after New Row added to the table
    }
```

But only 1st select working rest select is not working ..
Reference Table Image -

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages.
We'd like to see the minimum HTML and the JavaScript that demonstrates the problem *in your question*.

Answer (score 1):

The identifier element must be unique.
So you have to re-create an instance of Choices for each row with an unique identifier :

```
function addRow(table) {
        var x = document.getElementById(table);
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        var randomID = 'xxx'  //-> Random ID or something else
        new_row.setAttribute('id',randomID);
        $('#TableName tbody:last-child').append(new_row);
        new Choices('#'+randomID);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar kind of issue. First I give each element a unique class, and then make a call from JavaScript code:

My code is:

```
function runAnyChoice(selector, options){
    var element = document.querySelector(selector);
    var choices = new Choices(element, options);
    return choices;
}
```

And I call it like:

```
 var options_choice = {
     addItems: true,
     removeItems: true,
     removeItemButton: true,
     items: []
 };

runAnyChoice('.scope_tags', options_choice);
```

I think you need to get your multiple elements length first, then loop through each element and make a unique class or ID and call it in JavaScript:

```
$('#TableName tbody tr').each(function(index,elem){

    new Choices('.pdt-name_'+index);

});
```

It should work on each call.